# A good free IDE that installs with Boost for Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, ide

Does this exist?  Can someone recomend one if it does.  I was going to use minGW from the command line but Boost does not support minGW from the command line.

Figured I'd go ahead and try and install an IDE and Boost .

Comment: Boost does not support minGW from the command line?  What does that sentence even mean?  Are you looking for an IDE with Boost preinstalled?

Comment: sorry that command shell is not supported accoring to boost.org...http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: @user: All that's saying is that those particular instructions are not written with MSYS in mind.  MSYS is basically a bash shell and some other UNIX utilities, provided by the same people who provide MinGW and is meant to make the development process on Windows a little bit more like the development process on Xnix systems.  You don't have to use MSYS to use MinGW, and those instructions are written assuming you are using Windows Command Prompt.  Finally, it doesn't mean that you *can't* use MSYS with boost, it's just that those particular instructions will be little help to you if you do.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Ok, none of these actually *come with boost*. I don't know of an IDE that does (and frankly I don't know why it should). Installing Boost is pretty simple as it is. I interpreted the question to be:

> What nice windows IDE does support compiling with Boost?

- VS Express 2010 C++: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express
- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) and
- [eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) work with MingW

  - see http://ascend4.org/Binary_installer_for_Boost_on_MinGW
  - [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (thanks, Benjamin!)

    > My MinGW distribution ("distro") currently contains GCC 4.6.1 and Boost 1.47.0.
    >
    > [mingw-7.2.exe](http://nuwen.net/files/mingw/mingw-7.2.exe) (16.8 MB) : This is a self-extracting archive. It's incredibly easy to install; see [How To Install](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html#install) <strike>below</strike>.

Comment: Stephen Lavavej has an up to more up to date binary of MinGW(with GCC 4.6) with boost 1.47 and other goodies like SDL, zlib and libpng [here](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

Comment: VS Express 2010 C++ does _not_ come with Boost, though there's instructions all over the internet how to add Boost to it.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I thought that was so blatantly obvious, I just interpreted the question to _oviously_ mean: what IDE _works_ with boost. Sry. Clarified my answer. (**Edit** the OP said 'try and install an IDE **and** Boost' anyways)

Comment: just insalled code blocks...than saw that link to minGW boost....so intalled...http://ascend4.org/Binary_installer_for_Boost_on_MinGW

Comment: i don't know what that did but # inlcude still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I find BoostPro the easiest way to install pre-compiled boost binaries (libs, DLLs) and compiler pre-requisites (headers etc). http://www.boostpro.com/download/ (it's an installer that downloads whatever Boost modules you select and unzips them wherever you've told it to). All you need to do after that to use it is add the lib and include paths to your IDE/compiler. I personally recommend Visual Studio for Windows.

Comment: It should be noted that boostpro provides binaries *only* for Visual Studio.

Comment: BoostPro no longer exists.

Comment: It definitely still exists: http://www.boostpro.com/download/
Perhaps it's not being continued??? I see no obvious signs that anything has changed (it looks like it's still as active as ever).